# Can't get right-handed jQuery tabs to animate properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a combination of CSS and jQuery to create a set of tabs on the right side of the browser, and it works pretty much as it should with one flaw. The images that are present on the right side for the user to click and have the rest of the tab slide into view, just kind of "pop" over to where they should be instead of sliding, while the actual content slides in properly.

I've tried using .animate and other effects on the tab-handle-container class, but have been unsuccesful. I've posted my HTML, jQuery, and CSS code below for any tips you can provide. Also, I'm looking to have this work in IE8 and 9, not really concerned with other browsers at the moment. Thanks!

## HTML and jQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".myhandle").click(function(){
    $(".content", $(this).parents("li")).toggle('slide',{direction: "right"}, 1000);
    });
});

</script>


<html>
<body>
<div class="Container">
    <ul class="tab-list">
        <li>
            <div class="content">
            <h3>Contact Information</h3>
            <p>If you need technical assistance, please</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-handle-container">
        <img class="myhandle" src="contacttab.bmp"></img>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="content">
        <h3>Some more stuff</h3>
        <p>This will be where more content is displayed</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-handle-container">
        <img class="myhandle" src="email.jpg"></img>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```
html {margin: 0px;}

.myhandle { 
    cursor: hand;
}
.container {
right: -210px;
width: 240px;
height: 240px;
}
.tab-handle-container {
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
width: 40px;
float: left;
}
.content{
padding: 5px;
float: left;
width: 200px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are applying the animation to `.content`.  The image does not reside in `.content`.  Have you tried applying the animation to just the `li` or to both `.content` and `.tab-handle-container`?

Comment: MrSlayer I have tried adding a .animate to `.tab-handle-container`, it does not seem to apply the effect properly, or I'm coding it wrong. To your knowledge, is it possible to do a `.toggle()` that doesn't show/hide an element, but instead moves it back and forth?

Comment: Pass in two functions into the `.toggle( )` method.  See the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) for more information.

Comment: Ah, didn't even know it existed like that. Thanks, I'll experiment

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the help of MrSlayer using `.toggle` Threw both elements in a div, turned scrolling off via CSS, and then used this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myhandle").toggle(function(){
        $(".slider", $(this).parents("li")).animate({right: "+=200"}, 700);
     },
    function() {
        $(".slider", $(this).parents("li")).animate({right: "-=200"}, 700);
      }
    );
});
```